# Namespace confusion with variable definition and module / revealing module patterns

Tags: javascript

I am just about to get the hang of this, but I still have one question

I have 2 modules contained in their own js files. One is based on the module pattern and the other the revealing module pattern.  The confusion I have surrounds the assignment of a variable to these functions.  The code below should help

Revealing module example.  If I run this example I see a var1 variable in the global namespace with a doStuff public function

```
 var var1 = (function() {
     function doStuff() {

     };

     return {
       doStuff : doStuff
     }
 })();
```

Module pattern example.  If I run the example below in the debugger I can see the this.var2 line getting executed, but I do not see a var2 variable in the global namespace

```
(function() {
   function doStuff() {

   };

   this.var2 = doStuff;
})();
```

Just wonder whether anyone can help explain what is most likely my misunderstanding.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t see an issue with this code, when I run the second example, I find `var2` in the global namespace

Comment: I am using WebStorm and if I type var.  The only variable from a code completion perspective is var1  Not displaying a var2

Comment: I imagine WebStorm doesn't/can't work out that `this` inside your second module is referencing `Window`